# Imagening the Thurston geometries

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, philosophy

I can (more of less) imagine how it would look if space was Euclidean, spherical of hyperbolic.

But there are 8 Thurston geometries see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture

how would the big structure of the world look if we lived in one of the other 5 ?

Comment: You might like the answers to [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/30871/40804) question.